# Regular expression to validate a mathematical formula

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to validate a string using regex to confirm whether it is following a valid format.
The string can contain numbers, operators, space, dot, left parenthesis, right parenthesis, comma, these aggregate functions SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG and variables starting with letter V.

I found this regex ^[0-9+*-/()., ]+$ this checks 0-9 (numbers); '+'; '-'; '*'; '/'; '('; ')'; '.'; ','; ' '(space). But I am not able to include aggregate functions and letter V in this.

Some of the valid input strings are

1. `AVG(SUM(1, 2, 3), SUM(4, 5, 6)) * 100`
2. `SUM(V1/2,(2+7),3)+(V1+V2)`

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Are you trying to ensure that only valid characters, aggregate functions, and variable names appear in the string or are you attempting to also check that the string is well formatted (i.e. there is an operand on either side of an operator, parenthesis are matched, etc...)?

Comment: Did you consider using a real grammar/parser instead of a Regex?

Comment: this is not something that can be done by Regular expression, you stack to push operators, parentheses, ...

Comment: @D M I am just trying to validate only for valid characters

Comment: Is ^[A-Za-z0-9+-/()., ]+$ what you're looking for?

Comment: @DevMJ then `V+1SUM((((V1111((((V+` is valid, then?

Comment: See [Balancing Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments on the question:

> Are you trying to ensure that only valid characters, aggregate functions, and variable names appear in the string or are you attempting to also check that the string is well formatted (i.e. there is an operand on either side of an operator, parenthesis are matched, etc...)?
>
> - D M

> @D M I am just trying to validate only for valid characters
>
> - DevMJ

---

Since you're only looking to check that a formula contains digits, functions, variables, etc (and not that it is also valid for execution), you can add possibilities as alternatives in one group.

One possibility is the pattern `^(?:\d|\+|\-|\/|\*|\(|\)|\.|\,|AVG|SUM|MAX|MIN|V\d+| )*$` which matches the samples you provided.

[Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/jEMsDK/1)

Explanation:

| Token | Matches |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | Start of a line |
| `(?:` | Start of the non-capturing group of alternatives |
| `\d` | A digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`) |
| `\+` | The `+` character |
| `\-` | The `-` character |
| `\/` | The `/` character |
| `\*` | The `*` character |
| `\(` | The `(` character |
| `\)` | The `)` character |
| `\.` | The `.` character |
| `\,` | The `,` character |
| `AVG` | The string `AVG` |
| `SUM` | The string `SUM` |
| `MAX` | The string `MAX` |
| `MIN` | The string `MIN` |
| `V\d+` | The `V` character followed by one or more digits |
|  | A space |
| `)` | End of the non-capturing group of alternatives |
| `*` | Any of the alternatives zero or more times |
| `$` | End of a line |

---

As mentioned in the comments, if you also want to check that the string can be executed successfully, you will need to look into defining a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) for your "language" and using a tool like [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) to parse strings using the grammar.

Comment: This does not check the correct nesting of parentheses

Comment: OP specified in the comments that validity of the expression is not important, just that the expression only contains defined characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you care for is the valid characters, that's indeed a job for regexes.

A simple way to filter this is just to add letters to the valid characters:

`^[A-Z0-9+-/()., ]+$`

You can even add `a-z` if you want to allow lowercase characters as well.